# Car Rev Counter +200

Tags: engine, clutch, bmw, gears

When i change upto 3rd, 4th, 5th gear and put my foot on the acceleration my rev counter flicks up 2/300 rpm before returning to normal rpm. The best way to describe what it sounds and feels like is when you plant your foot down in an automatic and it drops a gear and accelerates it is like that but my car is a manual. I have had the drivetrain alarm come up 3 times now when ive been accelerating uphill but not sure its related. I have a short video of my rev counter in 5th gear if anyone is able to help me diagnose the problem that would be really appreciated. My car is a 2015 BMW 1 Series.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you post a link to your video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clutch is slipping. With a manual transmission, a brief RPM increase without a corresponding increase in vehicle speed can only mean a slipping clutch or spinning, smoking, screeching tires (and you didn't mention that!). If the effect only happens in higher gears, this confirms a slipping clutch.

Either your clutch friction surface is worn or it is contaminated by oil or another substance. Rarely, broken or weakened springs in the clutch can cause the same effect.

Comment: Assuming it is an actual manual transmission and not an automatic with a manual-ish UX, I would agree.